# I want to set the status code of a specific path to "404" GCP Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a HTTPS Load Balancer in GCP and I want to set the status code of a specific path to "404", I have this path https://my-domain/health/monitor

This path is used for the healthcheck, however it is a screen that I don't want to be accessed from the outside

Could you please tell me if there is a way to set the status code of a specific path (health/*) to 404 in GCP Load Balancers

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment we cannot set a custom 404 error in the GCP LB configuration, however, currently there is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/160192483) to add this functionality. As a workaround, I suggest you try to create your custom error pages (eg. [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/custom-error.html) or [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024199/nginx-customizing-404-page)) and set the [URL redirect](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#url-redirects) on your HTTP(S) Load Balancer -> [Host and path rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#path-matchers) configuration

Comment: thank you for have a look, I'll try your suggestion